# In a bitfiled structure does the controller read whole value or the particular byte

Tags: c

```
struct abc
{
    uint32 total;
    union
    {
        uint32 a:8;
        uint32 b:8;
        uint32 c:16;
    }
}
```

If i update or read "abc.b" then controller will read whole 32bits and update particular byte or does it directly read the byte and update it?

Comment: We don't know what the "controller" is or what it does. Or what you're doing with this structure really. Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. Also please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget to [edit] your question to include details about your "controller".

Comment: This is completely system-specific. Generally you can expect a 8 bit CPU to only read 8 bits, but a 32 bit CPU might read 32 bits if that gives more efficient code. Also, since bit-fields are so poorly specified, you don't know which bits in `total` that corresponds to `a`. Neither bit order nor endianess is specified.

Comment: It is unlikely you want a union for those bit-fields. If you want those bit-fields to be different parts of the `uint32`, then `union` should be `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

The C standard does not control how memory is accessed, except that declaring objects to be atomic imposes some constraints. Whether memory accesses of bytes, words, or other sizes are used to access bit-fields, or objects in general, is entirely dependent on the C implementation (primarily the compiler) and the target machine. If you have concerns about a particular system, you would need to identify it specifically, including the target hardware, the target operating system, and the C implementation being used.

If you have tried the code shown in the question and are not seeing the results you expect, it is likely because you have declared the bit-fields in a `union` instead of a `struct`. Declaring members in a `union` causes them to overlap in memory; `uint32 a:8` and `uint32 b:8` will refer to the same eight bits, and `uint32 c:16` will overlap them. To lay them out separately, instead of overlapping, change `union` to `struct`.